# Error class woocommerce to display product downloadable link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a function to display downloadable files url when a product is created and email.
I'm using the class `WC_Product` but I think it is not correct because the returns email me print `"Array"` in the variable $downloads.

My Function:

```
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'my_product_add');

function my_product_add($post)
{
    if ($post->post_type == "product") {
        $productId = $post->ID;

        $post_title = get_the_title($post_id);
        $tld_prod_url = esc_url(get_permalink($post_id));
        $subject = "Product Added Notification";

        $product = new WC_Product($post_id);
        $downloads.= $product->get_files();

        $to = "me@test.com";
        $body.= "The following product was added: \n\n" . $post_title . "\n" . $tld_prod_url . "\n" . $downloads . "\n\nThanks,\n";
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $body);
    }
}
```